Phase Correlation vs ECC for Image Registration: Unexpected Performance Difference
I'm working on an image registration problem involving shifting speckle patterns, and I've observed a significant performance difference between Phase Correlation and Enhanced Correlation Coefficient (ECC) methods. I'm trying to understand if this is expected behavior or if there might be an issue with my implementation.
Experiment Setup

Image Type: Circular speckle pattern, 125 pixels in diameter
Video Duration: 10 seconds at 30 fps (300 frames total)
Shift Pattern: Sinusoidal shift in both x and y directions

Shift parameters:
amplitude_x = 20
amplitude_y = 10
frequency_x = 1 Hz
frequency_y = 2 Hz
phase_x = π/4
phase_y = π/4






Observations
I've attached an image comparing the performance of Phase Correlation and ECC over time. The results show:


The Phase Correlation method consistently reconstructs the original shift signal with high accuracy throughout the video duration (they almost overlap on the plot).
The ECC method starts reasonably well but its performance degrades significantly over time, diverging from the true shift values.

Performance Analysis
Here's a quantitative comparison of the two methods:



Metric
Phase Correlation
ECC




Accumulated MSE
0.090509405
8.677650


Accumulated MAE
0.3588866
1.682454


Accumulated R²
0.999434
-38.827495



As we can see, Phase Correlation significantly outperforms ECC across all metrics, with a particularly stark difference in R² values.
Questions

Is this disparity in performance between Phase Correlation and ECC expected for this type of problem (shifting speckle patterns)?
What factors could contribute to ECC's degrading performance over time, while Phase Correlation remains stable?
Are there known limitations or sensitivities of ECC that could explain its poor performance in this scenario?
Is it possible that my implementation of ECC has a bug, or is this behavior typical for certain types of images or motion patterns?
Are there any modifications or alternative approaches I should consider for improving ECC's performance in this context?
Given the performance metrics, what might explain the extremely low (negative) R² value for ECC?

I would greatly appreciate insights into the theoretical or practical reasons for this observed difference in performance. Understanding this would help me choose the most appropriate method for my specific image registration problem and potentially improve my implementation.
